# React/Nodejs/Express - Routes not working on Azure Web App

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-devops

this is my first time making a nodejs app, and using express. I created the project using create-react-app. I am trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline using VSTS to deploy to my Azure Web App. I am able to get my React code working on the web app, but when I try to hit my Express route, it throws a 404, and renders the index.html file instead of retrieving the data.

Here is my file structure: [File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm0pQ.png)

My Package.json: [Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M0wK.png)

My Express server: [server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJjSL.png)

Also, here is my build VSTS:

[Archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFsxd.png)

[drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfO7d.png)

And here is my Release:

[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09GIZ.png)

And this is what is put onto the server: [Azure files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Fts.png)

When I run this locally, hitting localhost/api/getData returns my data as expected. But for some reason it does not work in production.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this for the last 2 days and I can't seem to find anything that has helped. I've read multiple forums, but none of the fixes they provide seem to be working. Thank you!

Comment: How did you solved this?